# Почему применение функции над map-объектом очищает его?

Tags: python, python-3.x, map

```
iterable = (0,1,2,3,4,)
map_obj = map(str, iterable)
print(list(map_obj))
# Вывод: ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4']
print(list(map_obj))
# Вывод: []
```

Такая же история и с объектом filter и *с другими функциями*
**Почему?**

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Итератор же, а не генератор?

Comment: @CrazyElf да, вы правы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`map` создаёт итератор, а по итератору можно пройтись только один раз. Чтобы пройтись по итератору ещё раз его надо создать заново. Вы проходитесь второй раз по итератору - и он не возвращает ничего.

Comment: зачем заново? `list(generator)`

Comment: @VictorVosMottor это создаст список из данных итератора, но сам итератор второй раз уже не обойти.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev это понятно, я имею в виду создал итератор, надо пройти несколько раз? превратить итератор в список и по нему проходит.

Comment: @VictorVosMottor Ну это понятно, обычно всегда так и делают - результат `list(map())` куда-то присваивают. Человека просто интересовало, почему так себя ведёт `map`, `filter` и другие подобные объекты.